# Dynamic Programming on Trees with Modifications

Tags: algorithm, tree, dynamic-programming, depth-first-search

Recently I read a problem on trees But I was finding difficulty in approaching this problem. Here is problem:

There is country with **n cities (2 to 10^5)** and **(n-1) bidirectional roads,** such that It is possible to travel between any pair of cities. We have **1 magic Truck** which can travel between cities but It will take **1 unit of time (if it's loaded)** and **0 unit time (if not loaded)** in traveling between adjacent cities, and **can hold at max 1 unit of product**.

Now You can have a customer in any city who requires **exactly 2 units of products** and cannot wait **more than 2 units of time.**

Now question is, we have to **minimise total number of storages** with given restrictions:

1. A city cannot have more than one storage.
2. A storage can only store 1 unit of product.

Assign Storages in country so that **you can fill atleast first order on time**. Given that order can be placed in any city.

**Time Limit: 1sec**

**What I have tried:**

1. Worst approach I can think is Brute force. Try to place storage in every city(2^n possibilities) and check if every city order can be fulfilled with help of neighbouring cities. But Time Complexity of this will be (n*2^n). So will not work at all.
2. Second approach I am thinking is using DP on trees somehow. And I am also not sure If this will be optimal. From above problem I can ensure that **leaves should have 1 storage for sure.**  And I was thinking DP like, start from root and check if children can help in fulfilling it's order and assign storage to that city accordingly, With base case on leaves. But problem Here is that children can also fulfil order from parent so it's making circular loops. So, It did not help me too.
3. Last approach I was thinking to apply binary search on answer itself. As answer can lie between(1,n) then answer may be found in nLog(n) order. But again problem is, I could not think an optimal way to assign storages in cities with given number of storages.

So, Thats it.. I was trying hard but could not solve this. Any help would be appreciated. :)

Note: I don't know why they make problem statement so complicated like this. They could easily explain problem in much simpler way. Resulting I cannot find this problem on web any more. It was somewhere on codeforces I guess.

Comment: I'd imagine that the answer would end up being something like https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/7478

Comment: @cdo256 I was reading that post, But when they are saying **Root the tree at some arbitrary vertex. For each subtree, compute the optimal dominating set (a) with the root, (b) without the root.**

I am feeling like this will make it of order 2^n. No??

Comment: No it'd be linear since it can be done greedily. That is, it takes the maximum of (a) and (b) for each node and forgets the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The important thing to note about the graph is that there are n cities and n-1 roads and all cities are reachable; this means that:

- There are no cyclic paths.
- There are at least 2 singly-connected cities (end-points).

There are two possibilities for every city; either:

- The city has a storage facility and another storage facility is a maximum of 2 cities away.
- The city has no storage facility, and is connected to at least two cities that have a storage facility.

This also means that a singly-connected city (end-point of a road) always has a storage facility, and a string of doubly-connected cities should (optimally) alternatingly have a storage facility or not, which will give us a starting point when deciding where to put the storage facilities.

[image: City storage animation]

<sup>blue: current node; green: storage; orange: no storage; +: needs another neighbour with storage; ?: visited but not yet solved</sup>

That gives us the following algorithm:

- Find an end-point first: start at any city and move in any direction
  until you come to a singly-connected city.
- Put a storage facility in the singly-connected city, then go back to
  the previous city, and mark the road to the city you came from as
  visited.
- If this city has only one other unvisited road, proceed down the
  unvisited road, leaving a trail of adjacent cities with and without
  storage facility.
- If you come to a city that has more than one unvisited road, wait to
  decide whether to put a storage facility and take any of the
  unvisited roads; later when you come back to this city and it has
  only one unvisited road, you will know whether any of the already
  visited neighbouring cities requires this city to have a storage
  facility.
- Do this until you end up in a city with no unvisited roads; this
  means you have gone through the whole graph.

This is basically a "travel down all roads and backtrack again" algorithm, so the number of visited nodes is 2×N and the complexity is linear or O(N).

---

It's worth noting that the order in which cities are visited will not change the result, i.e. the number of storage facilities, but it may change some of their locations. Consider these two solutions for 4 cities:

```
S - / - S - S   (solved left to right)  
S - S - / - S   (solved right to left)
```

---

Moving closer to actual code, let's see what to do once you've identified an end-point. The graph consists of nodes like e.g. this:

```
NODE "city" C1
- neighbours: [C2, C4, C7]
- has_storage: undefined          <- at first; will be set to true/false
- needs_more_storage: true/false  <- we'll add this property as we go
- visited: true/false             <- we'll add this property as we go
```

We start at an end-point, and then for each node, we'll:

- Mark the node as visited.
- Look at the neighbouring nodes: if you find only one that is undefined, determine has_storage for the current node: if all of the neighbours' *has_storage* are false or any of the neighbours' *needs_more_storage* is true, set the current node's *has_storage* to true; if not, set *has_storage* to false and set *needs_more_storage* to true if there is only one neighbouring city with storage; then move to the one undefined neighbour.
- If several neighbouring nodes are undefined, move to any of them that is unvisited.
- If none of the neighbouring nodes are undefined, you have reached the last node; this is always an end-point, so set its *has_storage* to true; the algorithm has now finished.

Comment: Nice.. But how can you prove that this solution will be optimal one?? and also, How can you justify that solution from following approach will not depend on which branch I take first.. Please help..
Earlier I was thinking a greedy approach.. such that assign storage to those nodes which will have max influence on network at ith state.. But could not think a way to prove if that will be optimal..

Comment: @KautsyaKanu I'll update my answer with some more details as I have time. If you run through some small examples, it's easy to see how this works.

Comment: @KautsyaKanu You'll see that any multi-linked city only has its has_storage set once all but one of the neighbouring routes have been fully solved. So you're solving from end-point to middle, and the endpoints have only one option, the rest follows logically; it's all in the order of visiting the nodes.

Comment: @KautsyaKanu It needs one more tweak: if has_storage is false, then you also need to store a count of how many neighbouring cities have storage. Only if that count is smaller than 2 is the last neighbouring city forced to have storage. I'll update the answer later when I have more time.

Comment: I am seeing a little flaw in logic here when you are saying **Only if that count is smaller than 2 is the last neighbouring city forced to have storage.** I was thinking an exception case like this, lets say There is a root A which has lets say 5 branches going away from it of height 1,2,3,4,5 (these are just straight branches so that we can assign nodes in them alternatively from leaf), Then even though root will have 3 neighbouring cities(neighbouring node of branch with height 1,3,5) with storage, still root has to have storage for sake of branches with height 2 and 4.. No??

Comment: From that I am thinking.. Root is forced to have Storage if either of it's neighbouring city cannot fulfil itself from all it's neighbouring cities.

Comment: @KautsyaKanu Yes, that's what my last comments were about; I've reworked the answer a bit (I added the needs_more_storage flag) and added an animation to show in what order the cities are visited.